# How can I use lm-sensors in Celsius?

Tags: temperature, kubuntu

I have done this before but I can't seem to find it again online, so I'm posting here to make it easier for future seekers (and to get an answer!)

I am using Kubuntu 14.04 and I have the `hardware sensors` widget running, but the temperatures are in Fahrenheit. I believe there is a system setting to change default temperatures to Celsius - how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1616285), I had to go to settings -> locale -> other and change the measurement type to `Metric System`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page `man sensors`, Celsius is the default unit of measurement reported when you run `sensors`. To get the reading in Fahrenheit you would use `sensors -f`

So most likely the configuration setting will be in the Widget you are using. The `cpu monitor` widget on my system (Debian + KDE v4.14.2) doesn't even display CPU temperature, just the CPU Load.

Comment: Apologies, I am using the `Hardware Temperature` widget.